# ngx-charts Line Chart Persistent Background

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-charts

I am trying to persist the line background that gets shown when I hover with the cursor on a value, like in the image below: [image: Graph]
Her is how I generate that graph:

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart
        [scheme]="sensorGraphData?.scheme"
        [results]="sensorGraphData?.data"
        [yAxis]="true"
        [xAxis]="true"
        [gradient]="false"
        [showGridLines]="true"
        [rangeFillOpacity]="0.9"
    >
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!